# Does the alternative universe Jotaro have Star Platinum?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

I am trying to understand *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Stone Ocean*'s ending.

> After Pucci died, the universe reset, creating alternative versions of Jotaro and the cast killed by Pucci.

Does the alternative Jotaro have his stand Star Platinum? The same goes for Jolyne: does she have Stone Free?

Answer (score 0):

The Stone Ocean ending is largely ambiguous. However, based upon the fact that Jolyne is named Irene in this universe, ending the 'Jojo' naming scheme, I'd guess she does not have a stand. The naming scheme because a tradition when the Joestars got the 'Joestar Curse'. For tradition to stop would imply that the curse is lifted, ending the series. Thematically, I think it would make more sense if she doesn't have a stand. In continuity, it would not make sense for any of the SO cast to have stands, as they all obtained stands via Pucci, or due to circumstances caused by Pucci, since Pucci's actions were erased, Irene, Anakiss, and Erme's alternate, never went to prison. Weather's alternate did not feel the effects of the arrow when Pucci was stabbed, as he was never stabbed.

As for Jotaro, there is no evidence that events uncaused by Pucci didn't happen as normal. Dio still awakened stands in Josuke, Jotaro. While Jotaro is never mentioned by name, it is likely his name is still Jotaro.